# How to check if user is logged in and display the user name

Tags: craftcms

I want to check if the user is currently logged in. If the current user is logged in I wanna display hello with a user name. How can I do that!?

Comment: Stack Exchange has its own dedicated site for CraftCMS, at https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/. You may have better luck asking this question there.

Comment: I didn't knew this... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if currentUser %}
{{ currentUser.friendlyName }}
     {% endif %}
```